# Apply a custom WP_Query to the whole multisite network

Tags: wp-query

I want to fetch all posts given a certain `meta_key` and `meta_value` restriction.

That can be done as follows:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'langpack_identifier',
            'value'     => 'whatever'
        )
    ),
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => '10'
);
```

And then using *get_posts()* or directly creating a new instance of *WP_Query*. But this will only fetch posts within the current site.

How can I extend the query so that it includes all results for all the sites in the network?

Comment: In 2020 i did this am sharing my own approach this approach works..
You can create your own custom plugin, then add the above code to that plugin.
Afterward, activate that plugin for all your sites. Let me know in case of any issues.

Comment: @RajneeshTiwari Thanks, but "the above code" will only extract results for the current visited subsite, not the whole network.

Comment: Check this solution may be this can help you out https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/how-to-list-posts-from-all-blogs-on-wordpress-multisite/